# A mixin for SCSS that checks for a body-class

Tags: sass

Is it possible to make a mixin (in SCSS), that checks adds styles based on the body-class (or a parent div).

The dream is to convert this:

```
#logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 20px;
} 

body.admin-bar #logo {

  #logo {
    top: 86px;

    @media screen and (max-width: 782px) {
      top: 92px;
    }
  }
}
```

... to this

```
#logo {
  position: absolute;
  @include adminAdjustedTop( 50px );
  left: 20px;
}
```

So `adminAdjustedTop` mixin then added the extra pixels to the top, if the `body` had the class `admin-bar`... So that the positioning of logo wasn't described in two different places, depending on which body-classes are set or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No mixin is needed to achieve this goal, you can simply use [parent selector reference](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#parent-selector) `&`:

```
#logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 20px; 
  body.admin-bar & {
    top: 86px;
    @media screen and (max-width: 782px) {
      top: 92px;
    }
  }
}
```